# Adding links to $content['links'] in theme layer

Tags: 7, navigation, theming

I know that I can use template_node_view_alter() or template_preprocess_node() in template.php, but the problem is, that some of the information that I can alter there, seems to be processed already. For example:

```
$variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title']
```

have some styling informations and a bit of text that is already translated. Is it possible to add a link even before, that structure was constructed? I don't want to overwrite something that was generated by Drupal for specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about overwriting what is there, just don't overwrite anything :)

The correct place for altering links is generally hook_node_view_alter(), as you mentioned.

For adding your own links it is hook_node_view()

As an example see http://drupal.org/node/224333#node_links

Answer (score 0):

Before the node, comes the page. To process before the page, try

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

}
```

And before the page, comes HTML. To process before HTML, try

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

}
```

This would also go into your template.php

UPDATE:

You'll first need to know what's currently in the `$variables` array. To do so, you'll need to install & enable the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module. Then insert `kpr($variables);` within the preprocess function. When you'll refresh the page, you'll see what's actually inside the $variables array.

If you want to modify `$variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title']`, you'd simply do this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] = 'title';    
}
```

Say, you want to keep the title, but want to add a `<div>` tag around it. This is where you need to follow Drupal [Forms API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

`['#prefix']` and `['#suffix']` will include string before and after form.

Here's the code:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['#prefix'] = '<div>';
  $variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
}
```

Don't forget to change MYTHEME into your theme name, check if $variables array of the item you're changing, actually exists, and flush cache.

Comment: But inside these hooks, is no information about links whatsoever. I doubt you can just add something there that will be processed to links, but if so, then how?

Comment: $variables array carries most of the data for your website. $variables array in preprocess_html, is used to build the html part of the page, then that information is carried to preprocess_page, where you can modify it again, then it carries the info to build the page, then it's carried to preprocess_node, where you can modify it again, then it carries the info to build the node, and so on.

Comment: I'll update my answer with more info

Comment: I've update the answer. See if that helps!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. These variables added to content at hook_preprocess_page doesn't seem to appear in $variables at hook_preprocess_node() and doesn't appear on page. They had to be overridden.

Comment: Go into your template.php, paste in "function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) { unset($variables['page']); }" without the quotes, don't forget to replace MYTHEME with your theme name. Did that make your page disappear?

Comment: If it did, you're in the right place, just setting the wrong $variables arrays. If it didn't work, you're either not in template.php, your template.php is in the wrong directory, or template.php has errors and you have your drupal messages disabled.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what was asked for. You would not generally deal with node links in preprocess page or html.